# BitmapLruCache for Volley Calculating the cache size?

Tags: android, android-volley

How does one calculate the bitmap size?  My understanding is it should support three full screens from the Google I/O presentation on Volley.  Does anyone know how I can calculate memory size for three full screens on any given Android device? I think this was referring to inmemory caching so a BitmapCache but not sure.

Now I have seen the following calculation suggested, but not sure if this is consistent with keeping three screens worth of data cached in memory.

```
 final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
 final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
```

UPDATE: What is the logic of using 1/8th of the total memory for cache. how does this compare to keeping three screens worth of data?

Thanks

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageCache;

public class LruBitmapCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> implements ImageCache {

public LruBitmapCache(int maxSize) {
    super(maxSize);
}

@Override
protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
    return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight();
}

@Override
public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    return get(url);
}

@Override
public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
    put(url, bitmap);
}

}
```

Comment: could someone comment on the maxMemory/8 reasoning?

Comment: What is the logic of using 1/8th of the max memory for Bitmap Cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the size of a bitmap that takes up the size of the screen, which I presume is what you're looking for, and store three of these bitmaps in an LRUCache of a set size which would correspond to the memory taken up by these bitmaps, would be:

```
// Gets the dimensions of the device's screen
DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int screenWidth = dm.widthPixels;
int screenHeight = dm.heightPixels;

// Assuming an ARGB_8888 pixel format, 4 bytes per pixel
int size = screenWidth * screenHeight * 4;

// 3 bitmaps to store therefore multiply bitmap size by 3
int cacheSize = size * 3;
```

From this, you should be able to work out the cache size you need to create to store these bitmaps.

Comment: Is 4 bytes per pixel a max?  are there formats that use more than 4 bytes per pixel?

Comment: Not that I know of for Android. The only two that come to my head which I use on the Android platform are ARGB_8888 and RGB_565, both of which have 4 bytes per pixel.

Comment: How could you compare using 1/8th of total memory to using 3 screens worth of memory cache?

Comment: Well, if you use an 1/8th of memory, that portion of memory becomes dedicated to your LRUCache, which may be more than you need for 3 bitmaps, therefore hogging memory that could be used elsewhere in your application. If you're only going to be using the LRUCache for 3 screen-sized bitmaps, you'd probably be better to use my calculation above to calculate the size.